# How do I restore my TFS source code from a SQL backup?

Tags: tfs

How do I restore my TFS source code system if I only performed a SQL Server backup? I went into SSMS and backed up the Tfs_Configuration, Tfs_DefaultCollection, and Tfs_Warehouse databases. Now, how do I restore them to a different machine?

Is there a document somewhere that explains what I need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

[Restore Data to a Different Server or Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516.aspx) (MSDN)